# App crashing when comparing map key to a comboBox.currentText();

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

so im making this currency calculator, and i run into some trouble with comparing a value selected in my comboBox and my map which stores the currency exchange rates.

(i wont post the code for map insert and combobox to be more speciffic, assume they arent empty.)

.cpp

```
class Calculator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Calculator(QMap <QString, double> &my_map,QObject *parent = 0);

    void get_value();

private:
   Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QMap <QString, double> *map_pointer;

signals:


public slots:

};
```

.h

```
Calculator::Calculator(QMap<QString, double> &my_map, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    map_pointer=&my_map;

}

void Calculator::get_value()
{

    QMap<QString, double>::Iterator i;

    qDebug()<< "im in get_value";

    for(i=map_pointer->begin(); i !=map_pointer->end();i++)
        if(i.key()==ui.>comboBox->currentText())
            qDebug()<<i.key() << ": " << i.value();


}
```

the app crashes on the if statement with "unexpectedly finished"

and my main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMap<QString,double> currency_map;

    MainWindow w(currency_map);
    w.show();

    Calculator c(currency_map);
    c.get_value();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: In the code you are showing, you don't assign `ui` in Calculator. If it's not in the coude you didn't post, it's uninitialized and causes the crash

Comment: you are right about that, but how come the Creator offers me the comboBoxes and all the other stuff i got in my MainWindow when i do ui->

and also how do you recommend me assigning the Mainwindow variable to the *ui ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member `ui` is not initalized and therefore causes undefined behaviour when accessing it. In your situation, the application crashes.

You must initialize the pointer to an instance of `Ui::MainWindow` before accessing it. A simple approach would be to pass the window in the constructor, like this:

```
// in .h
explicit Calculator(QMap <QString, double> &my_map, Ui::MainWindow *window, QObject *parent = 0);

// in .cpp
Calculator::Calculator(QMap<QString, double> &my_map, Ui::MainWindow *window, QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent)
{
    map_pointer=&my_map;
    ui = window;
}
```

However, I suggest that you restructure your program. It is bad design to have your calculator depend on the GUI. Instead, you should add a parameter to the `get_value` method, like this:

```
void Calculator::get_value(QString value) {
    for(QMap<QString, double>::Iterator i = map_pointer->begin(); i != map_pointer->end(); ++i) {
        if(i.key() == value) {
            qDebug()<<i.key() << ": " << i.value();
        }
    }
}
```

And pass the `ui->comboBox->currentText()` value when calling this function.

The creator's autocomplete mechanism suggest all the members of the ui because it is defined as a pointer to a `Ui::MainWindow` instance. This means, you **can** access its members via that pointer, **iff** it points to an instance. However, it will not check if your program correctly initializes the pointer during runtime.

You could use a code analysis tool like valgrind that will point out such problems

Comment: thank you very much for a detailed explanation.
ill make sure to check out valgrind as you recommended.